# Python: bot send a file during conversation

Tags: python, bots, python-telegram-bot

I have created a bot using python-telegram-bot module.

Bot generates barcode with the pybarcode module.

During bot conversation, I would like send to user the image created:

```
from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, KeyboardButton)
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, RegexHandler,
                      ConversationHandler)
from StringIO import StringIO
import barcode

#..............................
#..............................

def send_barcode(bot, update, user_data):
    fp = StringIO()
    generate('EAN13', u'5901234123457', writer=ImageWriter(), output=fp)
    #... how can I send the RAW image in fp object?
    #..............................................

#..............................
#..............................
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [bot.send_photo](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.bot.html?highlight=bot#telegram.Bot.send_photo). If you have file on disk use it like this: `bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('path/image.png', 'rb'))`. If you want to post file from memory there is example for it from [github wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#post-an-image-from-memory):

```
from io import BytesIO
bio = BytesIO()
bio.name = 'image.jpeg'
image.save(bio, 'JPEG')
bio.seek(0)
bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=bio)
```

Comment: Right! I suggest `bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open(str('path/image.png'), 'rb'))` because with python 2.7 you could have the error: `UnicodeDecodeError:...`

Comment: @Francesco If the answer has helped you feel free hit accept and both you and me will get points and others might find it helpful. I think change for python 2 is nota big deal and people will figure it out.